# Getting transactions from WebView with testing credentials (Plaid)

Tags: android, webview, plaid

How can I get transactions from WebView with testing credentials on Android?

This is my code:

```
public class PlaidViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plaid_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Initialize Link
    HashMap<String, String> linkInitializeOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
    linkInitializeOptions.put("key", "56632c5b63db7b7a155000b7c9507649");
    linkInitializeOptions.put("product", "transact`enter code here`ions,auth");
    linkInitializeOptions.put("apiVersion", "v2"); // set this to "v1" if using the legacy Plaid API
    linkInitializeOptions.put("env", "sandbox");
    linkInitializeOptions.put("clientName", "Test App");
    linkInitializeOptions.put("selectAccount", "true");
    linkInitializeOptions.put("webhook", "http://requestb.in");
    linkInitializeOptions.put("baseUrl", "https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html");
    // If initializing Link in PATCH / update mode, also provide the public_token
    // linkInitializeOptions.put("public_token", "PUBLIC_TOKEN")

    // Generate the Link initialization URL based off of the configuration options.
    final Uri linkInitializationUrl = generateLinkInitializationUrl(linkInitializeOptions);

    // Modify Webview settings - all of these settings may not be applicable
    // or necesscary for your integration.
    final WebView plaidLinkWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = plaidLinkWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

    // Initialize Link by loading the Link initiaization URL in the Webview
    plaidLinkWebview.loadUrl(linkInitializationUrl.toString());

    // Override the Webview's handler for redirects
    // Link communicates success and failure (analogous to the web's onSuccess and onExit
    // callbacks) via redirects.
    plaidLinkWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // Parse the URL to determine if it's a special Plaid Link redirect or a request
            // for a standard URL (typically a forgotten password or account not setup link).
            // Handle Plaid Link redirects and open traditional pages directly in the  user's
            // preferred browser.
            Uri parsedUri = Uri.parse(url);
            if (parsedUri.getScheme().equals("plaidlink")) {
                String action = parsedUri.getHost();
                HashMap<String, String> linkData = parseLinkUriData(parsedUri);

                if (action.equals("connected")) {
                    // User successfully linked
                    Log.d("-->Public token: ", linkData.get("public_token")+"");
                    Log.d("-->Account ID: ", linkData.get("account_id")+"");
                    Log.d("-->Account name: ", linkData.get("account_name")+"");
                    Log.d("-->Institution type: ", linkData.get("institution_type")+"");
                    Log.d("-->Institution name: ", linkData.get("institution_name")+"");

                    // Reload Link in the Webview
                    // You will likely want to transition the view at this point.
                    plaidLinkWebview.loadUrl(linkInitializationUrl.toString());
                } else if (action.equals("exit")) {
                    // User exited
                    // linkData may contain information about the user's status in the Link flow,
                    // the institution selected, information about any error encountered,
                    // and relevant API request IDs.
                    Log.d("User status in flow: ", linkData.get("status"));
                    // The requet ID keys may or may not exist depending on when the user exited
                    // the Link flow.
                    Log.d("Link request ID: ", linkData.get("link_request_id"));
                    Log.d("API request ID: ", linkData.get("plaid_api_request_id"));

                    // Reload Link in the Webview
                    // You will likely want to transition the view at this point.
                    plaidLinkWebview.loadUrl(linkInitializationUrl.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d("Link action detected: ", action);
                }
                // Override URL loading
                return true;
            } else if (parsedUri.getScheme().equals("https") ||
                       parsedUri.getScheme().equals("http")) {
                // Open in browser - this is most  typically for 'account locked' or
                // 'forgotten password' redirects
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                // Override URL loading
                return true;
            } else {
                // Unknown case - do not override URL loading
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Generate a Link initialization URL based on a set of configuration options
public Uri generateLinkInitializationUrl(HashMap<String,String>linkOptions) {
    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(linkOptions.get("baseUrl"))
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("isWebview", "true")
            .appendQueryParameter("isMobile", "true");
    for (String key : linkOptions.keySet()) {
        if (!key.equals("baseUrl")) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter(key, linkOptions.get(key));
        }
    }
    return builder.build();
}

// Parse a Link redirect URL querystring into a HashMap for easy manipulation and access
public HashMap<String,String> parseLinkUriData(Uri linkUri) {
    HashMap<String,String> linkData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(String key : linkUri.getQueryParameterNames()) {
        linkData.put(key, linkUri.getQueryParameter(key));
    }
    return linkData;
}
```

This is my code and I am getting the result in success

```
05-09 10:29:32.268 3091-3091/? D/-->Public token:: public-sandbox-2fddfc55-abb1-439d-84e0-6b1207503eb3
05-09 10:29:32.268 3091-3091/? D/-->Account ID:: nordpMwPjZSoVok6XzaeCQArXDjjM4H6Nj3ox
05-09 10:29:32.268 3091-3091/? D/-->Account name:: Plaid Credit Card
05-09 10:29:32.269 3091-3091/? D/-->Institution type:: null
05-09 10:29:32.269 3091-3091/? D/-->Institution name:: Citi
```

from this, I want to get transaction please help me out

Using postman i did 
https://sandbox.plaid.com/transactions/get

```
{
  "client_id": "5ae9627a6c0fcd0012c97bf1",
  "secret": "b67ff6d1a462303cf43e2e83edaf33",
  "access_token": "public-sandbox-2fddfc55-abb1-439d-84e0-6b1207503eb3",
  "start_date": "2017-01-01",
  "end_date": "2017-02-01",
  "options": {
    "count": 250,
    "offset": 100
  }
  }
```

but i am getting an error response

```
{
    "display_message": null,
    "error_code": "INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "error_message": "provided token is the wrong type. expected \"access\", got \"public\"",
    "error_type": "INVALID_INPUT",
    "request_id": "bTgTg"
}
```

like this please help out

Answer (score 1):

Old question, yet still writing this for the records
It looks like you were using public token as stated in your Postman request. You need to exchange the public token with an access token first, which would eliminate the need for direct communication between end user and plaid.

> "access_token": "public-sandbox-2fddfc55-abb1-439d-84e0-6b1207503eb3",

For the reference, Plaid access tokens start with `access-..` not `public-..`

For more information you can refer there.
 [image]
 https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#rotate-access-token